# Several MATLAB command windows possible?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to have several command windows (consoles) in matlab?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can start multiple sessions of MATLAB in different terminals or windows. Remember that you can use the command `matlab -nodesktop` to have a MATLAB session without the GUI, it's very useful to save space and memory.

Answer (score 7):

Within a single Matlab session, no. But you can run several sessions of Matlab in parallel on the same machine using a single license.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can start up to four individual sessions of MATLAB on a machine. But the behavior of the MATLAB startup program seems to be different depending on the OS and MATLAB versions.

On Windows, you may be able to start another session by just clicking the icon on the Programs Menu.

On Mac OSX, depending on the MATLAB version that you use, you may have to do 'Show Package Content' (right mouse click over the icon in the Applications folder) and directly double-click the executable file called 'matlab' under the /bin directory (or over its alias) to start another session.

On Linux, you can just type 'matlab' on the Console and start another session.